# Database as IPC antipattern

Tags: java, php, ipc, anti-patterns

I've written a layered web application that consists of a rich-web client (PHP) that interacts with a java service. The web client is hosted on an apache server, and the java service runs on the same physical machine (to reiterate: the entire app, client and service, are running on the same physical machine).

*User Request --> DB <-- Poller --> RequestHandler --> StoreResult in DB --> Web Client updates page with the result (AJAX).*

Communication between the client and service uses a relational database to pass messages. The java service has a single-thread poller, which looks for and then processes any messages/requests from the client. The system works, but I am not confident in my design choice.

Does anyone have any comments about this strategy? I've read that using a Database as IPC antipattern is poor practice, or at least an inappropriate one. However, the alternatives--XMLRPC, named pipes--seem to involve additional dependencies.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: You are using the database as a message queue. The thing you should look into is: does it make a good message queue? how about things like reliability (not miss a single message in any situation) and throughput?

Comment: Databases aren't really intended for queues/queuing.  They're used for persistence of the queuing software, like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/).  But some databases provide [native queue support (SQL Server)](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3640771/Getting-Started-with-SQL-Server-Service-Broker.htm)...

Comment: Something else: have you looked into Quercus?

Comment: @mario to me, the whole idea of Quercus seems unholy: why would you interpret and interpreted language using another interpreted language? (I know, java isn't quite interprested, but you get the piont)

Comment: Have you considered http://gearman.org/ - http://highscalability.com/product-gearman-open-source-message-queuing-system ?

Comment: I have done this once before and it worked reasonably well, although I wouldn't do it again. Two things, do not index the queue table and load the database from a memdisk to speed up reads and cut down wear and tear on the HDD. Keep in mind that most optimizations used to speed up reads on persistent data will slow down a db that's write-heavy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it were me, and I needed PHP to grab/consume data from a java service, i'd dump the DB.

Have the java service w/ HTTP listening on 127.0.0.1, port 5544 (or some random #).  Have a servlet/jsp take RESTful requests, and spit out JSON results.  So if its a search, the URL would be:

h ttp://127.0.0.1:5544/search_zip_code/80203

and the result would be simple json:

{ "city": "Denver", "state": "Colorado" }

and then on the PHP side do a curl request - build the URL with the parameters from the user input, do the curl request, get the data back and json_decode it ( $result_array = json_decode($curl_result); ).

It'd be simple.  This way, you can test either component easily (do a curl/wget from command line to test the java service, or check the access_logs on the server side to see the search parameters and the connection from the client).

For the PHP side, use curl_exec and json_decode (search for those functions in the PHP manual).

Here's a random link I found for the java side:

[Parsing JSON data with java servlet struts](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/02/creating-parsing-json-data-with-java-servlet-struts-jsp-json.html)

This way would be scalable (its easy to separate the services), modular (easy to test either component), and a lot faster for delivering results back to the client.

Comment: I agree! We ended up doing something very similar. Thanks, and my apologies for the delay in accepting this answer.

Comment: the linked page has moved, most probably here: [Creating &amp; Parsing JSON data with Java Servlet/Struts/JSP](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/creating-parsing-json-data-with-java-servlet-struts-jsp-json/)

Answer (score 1):

I see following arguments for DB as IPC:

1)You need to store all (or for some period) messages you ever received.

2)You need high reliability and don't want to loose any messages.

3)Perfomance of DB opposite sides is very different. In this way left client side can generate huge amount of messages and many clients on right side will process them. So DB is like passive load balancer with high reliability.

Do you need any of this features? I think no. You can't use it as load balancer because all processes are on the same host. And I think that you don't need to store all web requests.

In this case I would choose simple sockets.

Comment: Valid points. So, for sockets the client would need to open a socket and send it's message to the java service. Therefore, I would need to write code to manage the server sockets. How efficient is this? And what of reliability--the server socket crashing, etc. Also, how expensive would it be to open a client socket for every user request? Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Do your really need not to loose even one message? For web apps it's normal not to deliver some requests. User see an error and tries one more time. So generally you don't need high reliability for web apps.

Comment: Do your really need not to loose even one message? For web apps it's normal not to deliver some requests. User see an error and tries one more time. So generally you don't need high reliability for web apps. When you connect to DB you use sockets too but on higher level protocol. So you can reach more efficiency with raw sockets. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel you can use HTTP request from one service to another. Even with HTTP you will utilize less CPU and memory that with DB. Main point - understand prevailed features you really need and choose the appropriate protocol(or may be DB)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need message passing for PHP, just use ActiveMQ - just like message queues in UNIX IPC.
However database may be a good equivalent of shared memory and semaphores known from UNIX IPC.
So having ActiveMQ and database you can do the same you would be able to do with UNIX IPC, but it can be clustered if one server will be too little for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a hack, but it obviously works for you. [Here is a web site](http://www.freeopenbook.com/php-hacks/phphks-CHP-5-SECT-18.html) on how to implement a message queue with a DB table in PHP.